# SQL может ли поле одной таблицы быть связанным с полями других таблиц

Tags: sql

Не думайте, что автор вопроса настолько туп, сейчас я его объясню.
Пример: есть 4 таблицы:
1. Входящие документы (id, дата, содержание)
2. Плановые вопросы (id, содержание)
3. Повестки (id, дата)
4. Содержание повесток (id, id_повестки, содержание)
Логика процесса: поступают входящие документы, придумывают плановые вопросы, на определенный день формируется повестка, запись о которой попадает в таблицу 3, а всё то, что в эту повестку входит, содержится в таблице 4, и это могут быть и id_входящего_документа или id_планового вопроса, т.е. выглядеть так:
1 | 1 | 3(id вх док)
2 | 1 | 4(id вх док)
3 | 1 | 1(id план вопр)
Возможно ли вот так сделать? Или нужно как-то по-другому? Мысли зашли в тупик(

Comment: Я вижу 2 варианта. Или мы считаем плановые вопросы специальными видами документов, тогда связь потребуется только в виде id-повестки id-документа. Или мы делим содержание повесток на несколько таблиц: "документы повестки" где связь повестки с документами, "вопросы повестки" где связь повесток с вопросами

Comment: Видимо мне подходит только 2ой вариант, т.к. там есть еще и 3я сущность (не стал ее указывать в примере, но сути не меняет). Просто не очень хотелось еще плодить таблицы... Но получается что либо мне нужно создать таблицу в которой я должен объединить входящие документы, плановые вопросы и самоотчет (3я сущность) либо создавать дополнительные таблицы по маске содержание_повестки_вид_содержимого_1 и т.д. Правильно мыслю?

Comment: По-моему, первичный анализ или выполнен неверно, или вообще не проводился, а схема строится по некоему мистическому вдохновению... Пока я вижу только две сущности (входящая информация - документ или вопрос, и повестка как группа экземпляров входящей информации с дополнительными атрибутами типа даты), формально связанные как N:N. *не очень хотелось еще плодить таблицы* Количество (и содержимое) таблиц определяется исключительно предметной областью, а не какими-то там абстрактными хотелками. *либо создавать дополнительные таблицы по маске* Клиент не должен вообще иметь доступа к DDL.

Comment: Человек, который этот проект курировал свалил и теперь приходится самому всё делать.
В ходе работы над проектом уже не раз возникала ситуация, когда анализ с действительностью не совпадает, поэтому я и задаю этот вопрос.

Comment: Чисто гипотетически конечно можно сделать 3 поля со ссылками в одной таблице и контролировать что только одно из них заполнено. Это могло бы быть полезно если бы к фиксируемой в таблице связи сущностей полагались бы еще какие то поля не зависящие от вида связи. Но это очень спорное решение ... Так что если на повестке могут быть и вопросы и документы и друг к другу они особого отношения не имеют, то несколько таблиц выглядят наиболее корректно